# Getting HTML page with java hangs

Tags: java, html

I'm building a java program that reads a file from Remax.com containing ids from around 300 properties. I parses the html file of (www.remax.pt/(id)) and then writes some image URLs (found in the HTML page) into another file. It works well, but hangs in the middle of the process. Sometimes it writes 15 properties, sometimes 30 and sometimes 4. It seems random. I can't figure out when and why it hangs. It's probably something with the connection maybe?

Here's my code, more or less:

```
try {
    //initializing variables
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inputdir), "UTF-8"));

    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(ouputDir)), "UTF-8"));

    String line = "";

    int nProperty = 1;

    //reading Property id
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        id = line;
        //opening a connection to the property page, so i can grab the html and the images.
        URLConnection spoof = new URL("http://www.remax.pt/" + id).openConnection();
        spoof.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; H010818)");
        System.out.println(" Downloading photos from property " + nProperty + " - " + id);

        //getting an input stream to read the page
        InputStream in = spoof.getInputStream();
        try {
            InputStreamReader inR = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(inR);

            // searching the html page for the images i want
            while ((lineaux = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                if (lineaux.contains(".jpg")) {
                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("www.remax.pt/.*?.jpg");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(lineaux);
                    int i = 0;
                    int principal = 0;
                    String link = null;

                    while (m.find()) {
                        writer.write(m.group());
                        writer.newLine();
                        System.out.println("\t Downloading Photo " + i);
                    }

                }

            }

        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        nProperty++;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File Not Found");
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Then again, the code works. It's doing exactly what I want it to do, but hangs at random stages (I get no error -the program doesn't stop) and I have no idea what I can do to prevent it..

Thank You!

Comment: Maybe you can read the whole page first and then do the processing?

Comment: In the general case where a program you have written mysteriously hangs, you could attach a debugger to your program, and freeze its execution whilst hung.

Comment: @wool.in.silver could you show me how to do it with eclipse? I never used the built in debugger without breakpoints

Comment: @biip - Google it!!  I did, and I found this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda solved it. I had to do a spoof.setReadTimeout(10000); so it times out after 10 seconds and tries to connect again. It should be just a safety measure, but without it, the program doesn't complete.